# What options are required in a _config.yml file to run a GitHub Page?

Tags: html, yaml, github-pages

```
Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioactionsjekyllbuildpagesv104_2d9e9e --label 290506 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_DESTINATION" -e "INPUT_FUTURE" -e "INPUT_BUILD_REVISION" -e "INPUT_VERBOSE" -e "INPUT_TOKEN" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/luciennee.github.io/luciennee.github.io":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.4
  Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml
      GitHub Pages: github-pages v227
      GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.2
             Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
      Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1466:in `unlink': Is a directory @ apply2files - /github/workspace/_site/assets (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1466:in `block in remove_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1471:in `platform_support'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1465:in `remove_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:795:in `remove_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:582:in `block in rm'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:581:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:581:in `rm'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:104:in `write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:209:in `block in write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:332:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:331:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:331:in `block in each_site_file'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:330:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:330:in `each_site_file'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:208:in `write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:73:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-227/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-227/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `<main>'
         Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag
         Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript
         Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages
         Requiring: jekyll-gist
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
         Requiring: jekyll-paginate
         Requiring: jekyll-relative-links
         Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter
         Requiring: jekyll-readme-index
         Requiring: jekyll-default-layout
         Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings
   GitHub Metadata: Initializing...
            Source: /github/workspace/.
       Destination: /github/workspace/./_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       EntryFilter: excluded /CNAME
        Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 0.000141401 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 0.001776312 seconds.
        Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 4.6e-06 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 1.6801e-05 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 1.3e-05 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 7.9e-06 seconds.
         Rendering: assets/css/style.scss
  Pre-Render Hooks: assets/css/style.scss
  Rendering Markup: assets/css/style.scss
           Writing: /github/workspace/_site/assets/css/style.css
github-pages 227 | Error:  Is a directory @ apply2files - /github/workspace/_site/assets
```

New to programming and GitHub pages in general, but I was trying to push my repo onto the page, but got stuck in the Build with Jekyll stage. I've added a `\_config.yml` file, but the build message is still spitting out an error message. Is there certain requirements to include in a `\_config.yml` file?